# Finding the Minimum for columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data(x) as below where I would like to find the Min of all columns while preserving my row names(10,15 and 20). I tried `apply(x,2,min, na.rm=TRUE)` which returns result1, but I would like to get an output that would allow me to identify at which row I would get the min for a specific column. For example it identifies that at 15 the min for 'a' is 0.03; and at 10, the min for 'c' is 1.2.

```
x>
               a      b      c
   10          0.1    0.3    1.2
   15          0.03   0.01   6.90
   20          0.9    7.10   3.1


>Result1
a     b     c
0.03  0.01  1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve both row index and column name in your data, you could make a new column of the row name get data in wide format and select the minimum `value` in each column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column('row') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  slice(which.min(value))

#  row   name  value
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 15    a      0.03
#2 15    b      0.01
#3 10    c      1.2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(0.1, 0.03, 0.9), b = c(0.3, 0.01, 7.1), 
    c = c(1.2, 6.9, 3.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("10", "15", "20"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First line gives the minimum values for each column, and the second gives the location.

```
sapply(iris[, -5], min)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#     4.3          2.0          1.0          0.1 

sapply(iris[, -5], which.min)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#     14           61           23           10
```

Comment: Thanks. I have some NAN value in my actual dataset and the min return Inf for that although I included na.rm = TRUE to eliminate NAs value.

Comment: `sapply(iris[, -5], min, na.rm = TRUE)` should work and `which.min` doesn't require na.rm.

Comment: Best to give a small example of your data. It is rather weird `min` returns `Inf`(unless all you have NA's and Infs).